# Vim: pop-up window blinks while typing in Windows

Tags: windows, vim

I experience a lot of blinks while typing with YCM (YouCompleteMe) in Windows. (the file is fairly large, I use only identifier based completion in YCM; But in Mac and Linux with the same file, it doesn't blink at all and feels very smooth).

See attached screenshot for clues.

I guess this might not be YCM's problem, but anyone has any clues why this happens?

[image]

Comment: Any particular reason for posting this here rather than at YCM's [issue tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues)?

Comment: @lcd047 YCM doesn't officially support Windows, and they think it's Vim's problem. See https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1473

Comment: Then you might consider reporting the problem to vim_dev.  Chances of finding a solution here are vanishingly small...

Comment: @lcd047 thanks for reminding, I'll report to vim_dev.